# Predictive tableView swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 tableView with 2 tableView first to display data & sec for predictive texts and I'm using textField as searchBar so when I set the cell for the sec tableView is give me that error  when I try to return the cell at `cellForRowAt` method

Cannot convert return expression of type `UITableViewCell.Type` to return type `UITableViewCell`

and that's my code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == tableView {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchCell", for: indexPath) as! searchCell

    //cell.pics = receiveData[indexPath.item]

    cell.titleCell.text = receiveData[indexPath.row].adeTitle
    cell.cityCell.text = receiveData[indexPath.row].city
    cell.dateCell.text = receiveData[indexPath.row].date
    cell.distanceCell.text = receiveData[indexPath.row].distance
    cell.priceCell.text = receiveData[indexPath.row].adePrice

    if receiveData[indexPath.row].typ == "2" {
        cell.kindCell.text = "used"
        cell.kindCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        cell.kindCell.textColor = UIColor.white

    } else if receiveData[indexPath.row].typ == "1" {
        cell.kindCell.text = "New"
    } else {
        cell.kindCell.text = "none"
        cell.kindCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        cell.kindCell.textColor = UIColor.white
      }
    } else {
        var cell = searchTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell" )
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }
        cell?.textLabel?.text = inputs[indexPath.row]
    }
  return UITableViewCell
  }
```

Comment: i recommend to make your var names descriptive as say firstTbl or itemTbl / categoriesTbl

Comment: `return UITableViewCell` is the problem. You're returning `'UITableViewCell.Type` not an actual TableViewCell. If you changed it to `return UITableViewCell()` you'd be returning an instance and not get that error. However, what you really want to do is return the cell you configured. So just write `return cell`

Comment: As both of the answers below have pointed out (no idea why they have been down-voted) your line ‘return UITableViewCell’ is wrong. The return value from that method should be the ‘cell’ that you create in that method. So change it to ‘return cell’ as they advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `UITableViewCell`'s instance is not returned in your `cellForRowAt` method,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
  if tableView == tableView {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchCell", for: indexPath) as! searchCell
     ...
     // do your stuffs with cell
     ...
     return cell
  }
  return UITableViewCell() 
}
```